# Can't connect to computer after boot up

Tags: windows, boot, motherboard

I was cleaning a computer today and took out some of the parts (RAM, Hard Drive, Fans) just to clean them, and put them back into place after I was done, ensuring that they were fitted back correctly.

I usually connect to the computer via Remote Desktop, which needs to be connected to a network. (I cannot connect to a monitor because it has no video driver) However after putting everything back and starting up the computer, the computer looks fine but I can't connect to it via Remote Desktop.

Here's a full list of what happened:

1. Turned off the computer.
2. Disconnected the Power and Ethernet cables.
3. Touched the case, and used a metal screwdriver to touch the parts. (I don't really know but some people say it's to remove the static electricity)
4. Took out RAM sticks, Hard Drive and Fans and vacuumed them.
5. Put the parts back as they used to be.
6. Connected back the Power and Ethernet cables.
7. Turned on the computer.
   The computer made a single beep sound (about 1 second) then nothing happened. I searched online and read from [this website](https://itstillworks.com/one-beep-mean-computer-28943.html) that one beep means the POST was OK.
8. I turned off the computer and turned it on again. This time it just 
   turns on without making any sound like it usually does when starting up.

What I suspect:
-It could be that I plugged the Ethernet cable into a different port from when I switched the computer off for cleaning, so I'll have to get on to the computer and do the setting up in Internet settings. (But I can't because the only way I can control the computer is by Remote Desktop)
However, I tried two of the four ports (the sides because it was most likely that it was plugged into port 1 or 4) but to no avail.

UPDATE:
I managed to connect the computer to a monitor, and recorded a clip of what happened [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QP30qxMszU8EIU3FaHZyaVY6twe0P_5d/view?usp=drivesdk). I tried connecting a keyboard via USB to the computer but it didn't register anything.
Here's the text on the green screen if you can't read it:

```
Port 1: No device detected
Port 2: CDROM hp   DVD RAM GR80N
Port 3: No device detected
Port 4: No device detected
Port 5: No device detected
~(Can't read, probably a P)C1 BIOS installed

Initializing Intel(R) Boot Agent GE v1.3.98
~(Can't Read, should be a K)E 2.1 Build 091 (WPM 2.0)




The following configuration options were automatically updated.
Memory 20480 MB




F1 Save Changes        F3 Root Menu F10 Setup F12 Network
```

Comment: Which computer model? Does the computer boot? Do you have a connected display and what do you see? Does the internet work?

Comment: Q1 - Don't know what you mean by "computer model" but its a hp computer, if you are asking about the processor it's an Intel Xeon. Q2 - I'm pretty sure it boots, because the power button lights up and the Ethernet lights are working fine. Q3 - As I said above, the computer has no video driver so it cant display to a montior. Q4 - If you are asking about the router, yes it works and Internet is connected. If you are asking about on the computer, all that I know is that the Ethernet cable has a green and orange light. (Which means connected)

Comment: If SSH does not work, the only solution I can see is to to connect a display (and a video card if required). Otherwise, there is no way to know what went wrong.

Comment: If you plugged up to a different port the machine will have set up a new interface which you'll have to configure… by attaching a monitor. Windows is terrible for doing that. The one I'm currently remoted to thinks it's on "Network 5" which means it's done that 4 times before, for no good reason whatsoever. […or you could get lucky & swap the ports back over…]

Answer (score 0):

Whilst hovering did you touch any of the parts? it's my experience that hovers can get static build-up and cause damage (especially to ram).

I am guessing you tried the grounding after disconnecting the power, in which case, it probably didn't work, it's you that needed the grounding, and the PC needed connected to earth (the power) to do this.

So you need 3 things pluggged into you computer, power, keyboard and screen. when you say no video driver, I am assuming you mean no video card?  That's incredibly rare, even my servers that I remote connect to have video output of some sort. Most PC wouldn't start without a video card of some sort.

if you don't get any video post with just those 3 things plugged in, there is likely a hardware fault of some sort.

If you can't connect a monitor, depending on your OS, you are going to be shooting in the dark.

As you only have beep codes to go on. try the computer with the ram plugged in and not plugged in to see if you have the same beeps.  From what you have listed that's about all that's going to change the beep codes.

If it's the same for both, that's bad.

if you can get it to boot, watch for a flashing HDD light (that's good)
And with the ethernet etc connected try pinging it.

Come back any let us know the results of those efforts

Comment: Ok, I tried removing the RAM and starting it up, it makes a continuous beep sound, so it is not hardware damage. I tried plugging the Ethernet cable into the computer's four ports, waited a few minutes, tried to connect via Remote Desktop, no success. Also, I noticed something strange. When I press the power button, the computer cuts of power immediately, which is strange as usually it takes a minute to shut down before turning off. I will try to connect the computer to a monitor but that will take a few days. Will update you.

Comment: I think the fact that it shuts off immediately could be a problem. What do you think?

Comment: OK, that's good (in a way), the RAM isn't fried by the sounds of it. A monitor will give us a lot more clues as to what is going on. We might have a quantifiable error to work with. The shutdown thing could be a few things, so lets not panic.  It's pretty rare for a PC of any description to have more than 1 NIC (ethernet port), I have never seen one with 4 (not saying they don't exist, they are just rare, and I have never been anywhere, where one was needed), can you give us more details on the actual hardware you are working with, that might give a little more insight.

Comment: I managed to connect to a monitor. Read the main text for the updates.

Comment: Any updates? Still waiting for a response.

Comment: Sorry been away for a few days. You have no hard disc listed as attached. I suspect you forgot to plug something in again. Either power or the (probably) sata cable to the hard disc.  This [how to install a hard drive on PCWorld](https://www.pcworld.com/article/131231/how-to-install-a-new-hard-drive-in-your-desktop-pc.html) might help you. It has a few images on how to do it, might give you a clue as to what you missed.

Comment: Also it should not matter which lan port you are plugged into on the router/switch/hub, I am assuming from comments (Q4) only one lan port on the PC.

Answer (score 0):

As your question and other comments if I am not wrong and understood  that

1. You have 2 CPU computers
2. First CPU PC don't have display driver so u don't connect monitor
3. You access the 1st CPU and connect it through remote desktop

If I am right then kindly answer the following

A. As display driver is necessary in windows not in safe mode or dos or bios you can connect monitor and check display is coming or not and checking safe mode windows booting or not

1. If you need inbuilt graphic card driver open CPU and find mothe bord modwl number and chwck deivee on company website
2. Download and run CPUZ software tool in safe mode and find motherboard manufacturer model or chipset number note it
3. Find HP model number or motherboard model number and search its on number on google and find its driver download it install it or tell us model number we can find and give you the link of drivers

B. If internal or external display card is not working then you can  purchase buy add a display card old on PCI or PCIe and check display of CPU or windows

C. If you want to work blindly on guess then do follow following steps

1. Power on 1st CPU that you cleaned
2. One small beep means that you have been switched on and after POST but it does not means that you are booted to  OS windows
3. Connect headphone or speaker to first CPU u will get windows music or u can see HDD light blinking and then stable after 5 min
4. If no sound press F1 or enter to bypass any bios error or any error dialogue box or any error till you listen windows booting sound in speaker or headphone
5. When u listen booting sound it will confirm that windows is switched on and you are in desktop if CPU blindly
6. Now on second CPU go to start run type

   Ping -t 192.168.1.20 (IP address of 1st CPU)

If its showing request timed out  it 1st CPU card or land cable not connected means or  not connected

If its showing hardware error then 2nd CPU card or driver cable router switch not working

If its showing TTL ms  its means connection is working fine

Then you can check your  networking and play with remote desktop

For further queries feel free to ask questions or problems